# Documentation for vifm?

Tags: vim, file-manager, vifm

[image]

`vifm` looks like a good file manager, but it lacks documentation. Is there a manual or tips on how to use it? I'm looking for information on copying/moving a dir, creating a new empty file, editing a file, creating sym/hardlink, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is some helpful documentation in `/usr/local/share/vifm/vifm-help.txt` and `/usr/local/share/vifm/vifm.txt` -- in addition to the man page.

The Arch wiki also has a [Vifm page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vifm) with some tips on using it.

Essentially, as the name suggests, it is like using Vim for managing your files. Copy or move is <kbd>yy</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>. Edit is <kbd>e</kbd>.

As it is programmable, you could create a symlink with this in your `.vifmrc`

`COMMAND=ln=!ln -s %d/%f %D`

Comment: :D good one, thx